# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta xpath correctamente que filtre con un predicado?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsl, xquery

Hola chicos estoy realizando una consulta de tipo xpath en un archivo xsl pero creo que no es del todo correcto, solo necesitaría saber como hacer la opción b correctamente gracias de antemano, pego el código, xml y xsl

Los requerimientos que ha de cumplir la hoja se muestran a continuación:

a) Se realizará una vinculación correcta entre el archivo XML y la hoja de estilos (que se llamará LMSGI05J.xsl).

b) La tabla mostrará un registro para cada chat de tipo “G” (grupo), filtrando los “C”.

c) La columna “miembros” contará la cantidad de miembros pertenecientes al grupo.

d) La columna “mensajes” hará lo mismo con los mensajes que hay dentro de ese chat.

```
<guasap>
<contactos>
    <contacto id="CTO001" nombre="Javier"/>
    <contacto id="CTO002" nombre="Marta"/>
    <contacto id="CTO003" nombre="Carlos">Hi there, I'm using guasap</contacto>
    <contacto id="CTO004" nombre="Reyes"/>
    <contacto id="CTO005" nombre="Aniceto">No soy agente secreto, ese era Anacleto</contacto>
    <contacto id="CTO006" nombre="Miguel"/>
    <contacto id="CTO007" nombre="Berny">No me llames Bernarda</contacto>
    <contacto id="CTO008" nombre="Claudio"/>
    <contacto id="CTO009" nombre="Teresa"/>
</contactos>
<chats>
    <chat id="CH001" tipo="C" contacto="CTO004">
        <msgs>
            <msg id="M001001" ts="2021-03-01T15:20:23" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO004">Hola</msg>
            <msg id="M001002" ts="2021-03-01T15:28:38" tipo="texto">Hey, perdona estaba despistado</msg>
        </msgs>
    </chat>
    <chat id="CH002" tipo="C" contacto="CTO002" silenciado="2021-07-15">
        <msgs>
            <msg id="M002001" ts="2021-03-01T11:12:31" tipo="texto">Oye</msg>
            <msg id="M002002" ts="2021-03-01T11:12:38" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO002">Dime</msg>
            <msg id="M002003" ts="2021-03-01T11:12:42" tipo="texto">Tengo que contarte algo, mejor por audio...</msg>
            <msg id="M002004" ts="2021-03-01T11:13:02" tipo="audio" media="https://media.guasap.es?tkn=445ac65e657f515b" dura="45" />
            <msg id="M002005" ts="2021-03-01T11:14:51" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO002">Vaya tela</msg>
        </msgs>
    </chat>
    <chat id="CH003" tipo="G" contacto="CTO001" nombre="Brothers">
        <miembros>
            <miembro contacto="CTO003" />
            <miembro contacto="CTO008" />
        </miembros>
        <msgs>
            <msg id="M003001" ts="2021-03-01T10:08:01" tipo="texto">Necesito saber quien viene esta mañana</msg>
            <msg id="M003002" ts="2021-03-01T10:12:11" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO008">Yo voy, pero sobre las 13:00</msg>
            <msg id="M003003" ts="2021-03-01T10:12:48" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO003">Yo no puedo, lo siento</msg>
        </msgs>
    </chat>
    <chat id="CH004" tipo="G" contacto="CTO006" nombre="Amigos">
        <miembros>
            <miembro contacto="CTO005" />
            <miembro contacto="CTO007" />
            <miembro contacto="CTO009" />
        </miembros>
    </chat>
</chats>

<h2>Resumen de grupos</h2>
```

```
<xsl:for-each select="/guasap/chats/chat[@tipo='G']">
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@nombre"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="count(/guasap/chats/chat/miembros)"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="count(/guasap/chats/chat/msgs)"/></td>
</tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas simplemente una expresión relativa, como por ejemplo en `count(msgs/msg)`, se cuenta solo los elementos `msgs/msg` del elemento `chat` seleccionado en la instrucción `for-each`:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Chat</th>
                <th>Miembros</th>
                <th>Mensajes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="/guasap/chats/chat[@tipo='G']">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@nombre"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="count(miembros/miembro)"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="count(msgs/msg)"/></td>
            </tr>
             </xsl:for-each>                    
        </tbody>
    </table>
```